# Howto make namespace attribute with groovy xml builder

Tags: xml, groovy, namespaces

How can i create an attribute with a namespace? To get the following output?

```
<tns:catalogItem xsi:type="specialItem" />
```

This is how i do it yet:

```
catalogItem( type:"specialItem");
```

But this generates the attribute without namespace, so its invalid

```
<tns:catalogItem type="tns:specialItem" />
```

so i'm searching for something like this (with initialized xsi for ns):

```
catalogItem( xsi.type:"specialItem");
```

Thank you in advance

chrsk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Groovy code:

```
def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
xml.'rec:records'('xmlns:rec': 'http://groovy.codehaus.org') {
  car(name:'HSV Maloo', make:'Holden', year:2006) {
    country('Australia')
    record(type:'speed', ' Truck with speed of 271kph')
  }
}
```

results in this XML:

```
<rec:records xmlns:rec='http://groovy.codehaus.org'>
  <car name='HSV Maloo' make='Holden' year='2006'>
    <country>Australia</country>
    <record type='speed'> Truck with speed of 271kph</record>
  </car>
</rec:records>
```

More [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Creating+XML+using+Groovy%27s+MarkupBuilder).

Comment: This works very fine, thank you. Sorry i didn't found this article of groovy codehaus.